# Reactjs useFrom Hook - Update form value while typing on input field

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

My Login form works fine if I click Login Button with `mouse`.
But for user experience purpose when a user clicks the `ENTER` key on keyboard, I need the same validation.

How I can get updated entry value when user clicks `ENTER` key.
I am suing useForm from react-router-dom.

This is my code:

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

function Login() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const handleLogin = async (entry) => {
    if (!entry.username.trim()) {
      console.log("Username is required");
    } else if (!entry.password.trim()) {
      console.log("Password is required");
    } else {
      console.log("great...");
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleLogin)}>
      <div>
        <label>Username</label>
        <div>
          <input
            className="login-input"
            type="text"
            id="username"
            {...register("username")}
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>Password</label>
        <div>
          <input
            className="login-input"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            {...register("password")}
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" className="submit-btn">
        Login
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding using the `onKeyDown` event attribute.

```
// e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey is to check if it's a Mac or Windows in use
  onKeyDown={(e) => {
        if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) &&
          e.key === "Enter"
        ) {
          handleLogin(args);
        }
      }}
```

full implementation

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

function Login() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, getValues } = useForm();

  const entryValues = getValues();

  const handleLogin = async (entry) => {
    if (!entry.username.trim()) {
      console.log("Username is required");
    } else if (!entry.password.trim()) {
      console.log("Password is required");
    } else {
      console.log("great...");
    }
  };

  return (
    <form
      onKeyDown={(e) => {
        if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && e.key === "Enter") {
          handleLogin(entryValues);
        }
      }}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleLogin)}
    >
      <div>
        <label>Username</label>
        <div>
          <input
            className="login-input"
            type="text"
            id="username"
            {...register("username")}
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>Password</label>
        <div>
          <input
            className="login-input"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            {...register("password")}
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" className="submit-btn">
        Login
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default Login;
```